# How to add blur in/out to asymmetric transitions in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a slide in / out effect with opacity change that is achieved through following SwiftUI transition

```
VStack {

}
.transition(
  .asymmetric(
    insertion: .opacity
      .combined(with: .offset(x: 50)),
    removal: .opacity
      .combined(with: .offset(x: -50))
  )
)
```

In addition to opacity change and offset I would like to "blur in" the view on insertion and "blur out" the view in removal step. Unfortunately it looks like SwiftUI doesn't offer `.blur` transition to combine with here, so I wanted to ask if it is possible to add these kinds of custom transitions somehow and combine with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I'm using a simpler animation since it's identical to the one you've provided</sub>

#### Method 1: Apply Modifier To A Conditional View

Wrap the conditional view in a group and apply the blur based on the conditions like:

```
Group { //  Wrap the condition
    if showDetails {
        Text("This is the label")
            .transition(.opacity.combined(with: .offset(x: -50)))
    }
}
.blur(radius: showDetails ? 0 : 10) //  Use the modifier on the group
```

##### Demo

[image: Demo]

---

##### Method 2: Custom Transition

You can create a custom transition using a custom `AnimatableModifier`.

@Baffo rasta has mentioned [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77638610/5623035) before I have time to complete my answer and should have the credit, but here is mine which is some sort of refactored version of his:

```
struct Blur: AnimatableModifier {
    init(radius: Double = 0) { animatableData = radius }
    var animatableData: Double

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.blur(radius: animatableData)
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    static var blur: AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.modifier(active: Blur(radius: 10.0), identity: .init())
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
.opacity
    .combined(with: .offset(x: -50))
    .combined(with: .blur) //  Combine with other transitions
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import SwiftUI

struct BlurAnimationModifier: AnimatableModifier {
    
    var blur: Double

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { blur }
        set { blur = newValue }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .blur(radius: self.animatableData)
    }
}



extension AnyTransition {
    static var blur: AnyTransition {
        get {
            AnyTransition.modifier(
                active: BlurAnimationModifier(blur: 5.0),
                identity: BlurAnimationModifier(blur: 0.0)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
.transition(
    .asymmetric(
        insertion: .opacity
            .combined(with: .offset(x: 50)),
        removal: .opacity
            .combined(with: .offset(x: -50))
    ).combined(with: .blur)
)
```